# Is there any advantage to using a <StackLayout> or <Grid>?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The code I have looks like this:

```
<ListView.Header>
   <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <StackLayout Padding="10,35,10,10" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
         <local:ExtLabel ExtStyleId="Body" Text="Custom body Label"></local:ExtLabel>
         <local:ExtLabel ExtStyleId="Header" Text="Custom hdr Label"></local:ExtLabel>
      </StackLayout>
   </StackLayout>
</ListView.Header>
```

Would it be possible to implement this with a `<Grid>` and does the `<Grid>` offer more flexibility than `<StackLayout>` ?

Answer (score 6):

I think you might want to have a look at [this](http://kent-boogaart.com/blog/jason-smith's-xamarin-forms-performance-tips) excellent blog post about this. The source is an employee from Xamarin, even more so, one of the founders of Forms.

A few of the bullets in reference to Layouts:

> - **DO NOT** use a `StackLayout` to host a single child.
> - **DO NOT** use a `Grid` when a `StackLayout` suffices.
> - **DO NOT** use multiple `StackLayout`s when a `Grid` suffices.
> - **DO** use a `Grid` to achieve layering.

In regard to looks, you could achieve the same with both. In regard to performance, take a look at the full blog post (and these rules) to decide what is the better option.

Comment: I was about to add the link of Jason's Smith talk at Evolve but just noticed the link to the blog post you added already has it. That talk is The Talk about performance in Forms!